# A question about expectation of chromatic number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

For a graph $G$, let $G_{1/2}$ be the subgraph of $G$ that each edge of $G$ is included independently with probability.

Then for $H=G_{1/2}$, after a moment thought, it can be proved that $\chi(H)\chi(H^c)\ge \chi(G)$ by coloring each vertex of $G$ by $(c_1,c_2)$ for color $c_1$ in the coloring of $H$ and $c_2$ in that of $H^c$, where $H^c$ stands for the complement graph of $H$ and $\chi(G)$ stands for the vertex chromatic number of $G$.

A statement says that it implies $\mathbb{E}(G_{1/2})\ge\chi(G)^{1/2}$. I am wondering why this statement is true.

I think the above argument only implies $\mathbb{E}(\chi(H)\chi(H^c))\ge \mathbb{E}(\chi(G))=\chi(G)$, even if we know $\mathbb{E}(\chi(H))=\mathbb{E}(\chi(H^c))$ (but they are not independent so we don't know $\mathbb{E}(\chi(H)\chi(H^c))= \mathbb{E}(\chi(H))\mathbb{E}(\chi(H^c))$?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use AM-GM inequality to get
$$
\frac{\chi(G_{1/2})+\chi(G_{1/2}^c)}{2} \geq \left(\chi(G_{1/2})\chi(G_{1/2}^c)\right)^{1/2}\geq \left(\chi(G)\right)^{1/2}.
$$
Now note that $G_{1/2}$ and $G_{1/2}^c$ have the same distribution, therefore, taking expectation you get left-hand side of the above equation is $\mathbb{E}(\chi(G_{1/2}))$.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the FKG inequality: note that $\chi(G_p)$ is increasing with respect to $p$, where $G_p$ is the subgraph of $G$ that each edge of $G$ is included independently with probability $p$ (and $\chi(G_p^c)$ is decreasing). Therefore
$$[\mathbb{E}(\chi(H))]^2=\mathbb{E}(\chi(H))\mathbb{E}(\chi(H^c))\ge \mathbb{E}(\chi(H)\chi(H^c))\ge\chi(G).$$

Comment: $G_p$ seems like a random variable. Maybe you should say something like that $\chi$ is increasing wrt. the poset of subgraphs of $G$.

Comment: Good comment! I revised the answer to make it rigorous.